# Items not constrained properly in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to create a ConstraintLayout containing a complex layout but for some reason, it won't appear in the way that is expected. Does anyone know what must be done in order to fix the constraints and achieve the expected outcome?

**XML layout code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/lightgrey"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mymap"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="41dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewSun"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_sun_black"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/switch_stationstopmap_lighttheme"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch_stationstopmap_lighttheme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewMoon"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_moon_black"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.508"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/switch_stationstopmap_lighttheme"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Expected result**

[image]

**Current result**

[image]

**Desired requirements**

[image]

1. The `MapView` height needs to be 90% of the layout's height
2. The height underneath for the 3 items needs to be 10% of the layout's height
3. The `Switch` needs to be exactly in the horizontal centre of the screen
4. The 3 items (both image views and Switch) need to be exactly in the vertical centre of the 10% height for point 2
5. The `ImageView` of the sun needs to be exactly halfway horizontally between the left hand side of the screen and the switch
6. The `ImageView` of the moon needs to be exactly halfway horizontally between the switch and the right hand side of the screen
7. 5dp margin is required for both the top and bottom of the 10% height at the bottom of the layout (for the 3 items)
8. All of the above should result in the **expected result** image, which is what I want.

Comment: One of the weird things I see in your layout is `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"` applied to the map. This is making the map to disappear, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. I changed your root layout height to `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and then most of the issues are solved.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">
    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mymap"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#f00"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewSun"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/switch_stationstopmap_lighttheme"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"
        />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch_stationstopmap_lighttheme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewSun"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/imageViewMoon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewMoon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/switch_stationstopmap_lighttheme"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```